# Android app works with ESP8266 using router as WAP but ESP8266 doesn't work with soft access points

Tags: android, arduino-esp8266, wap

I have an Android app I made using MIT App Inventor which works with the following ino file in the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid     = "my ssid";
const char* password = "my password";

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Auxiliar variables to store the current output state

// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
int tool_box_lights = 0;
int pass_side_lights = 0;
int drv_side_lights = 0;
int rear_lights = 0;
int winch = 0;

// Current time
unsigned long currentTime = millis();
// Previous time
unsigned long previousTime = 0; 
// Define timeout time in milliseconds (example: 2000ms = 2s)
const long timeoutTime = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
//    Serial.println("New Client");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) { // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();         
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
//        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            //Serial.println(header);
            // turns the GPIOs on and off
            if (header.indexOf("/tb/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("toolbox on");
              client.println("toolbox on");
              tool_box_lights = 1;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/tb/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("toolbox off");
              client.println("toolbox off");
              tool_box_lights = 0;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/ps/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("pass side on");
              client.println("pass side on");
              pass_side_lights = 1;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/ps/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("pass side off");
              client.println("pass side off");
              pass_side_lights = 0;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/ds/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("drv side on");
              client.println("drv side on");
              drv_side_lights = 1;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/ds/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("drv side off");
              client.println("drv side off");
              drv_side_lights = 0;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/rr/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("rear lights on");
              client.println("rear lights on");
              rear_lights = 1;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/rr/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("rear lights off");
              client.println("rear lights off");
              rear_lights = 0;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/wc/in") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("winch in");
              client.println("winch in");
              winch = 1;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/wc/out") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("winch out");
              client.println("winch out");
              winch = 2;
            } else if (header.indexOf("/wc/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("winch off");
              client.println("winch off");
              winch = 0;
            }  
            // Display the HTML web page
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
//    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
//    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

but when I try to make it work with soft access points:

```
    IPAddress local_IP1(192,168,0,22);
    IPAddress gateway1(192,168,0,1);
    IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
    ...
      Serial.print("\nSetting soft-AP configuration ... ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP1, gateway1, subnet) ? "Ready" : "Failed!");
      Serial.println(WiFi.softAP(ssid, password, false, 4) ? "Ready" : "Failed!");

      Serial.print("Soft-AP IP address = ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

      // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    /*
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    */
      // Print local IP address and start web server
      Serial.println("");
    //  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
      Serial.println("IP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
      server.begin();
    }

    void loop(){
      WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    Serial.println("New Client");          // print a message out in the serial port
...
```

It never connects. I tried leaving out where I was manually setting the IP address:

```
IPAddress local_IP1(192,168,0,22);
IPAddress gateway1(192,168,0,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
```

and it came out to be `192.168.1.4`, so I set that as the IP address in MIT App and I get an 1103 error. Here's part of the block code for that:

[image: MIT App Inventor Block Diagram]

The only thing I change is the IP address. It works fine if I use the router's IP address, but I want to use this in my truck and don't want to have to carry a router around.

Comment: Edit: I'm setting a totally different ssid/password when using soft access points.

Comment: What is a soft access point? Please explain your setup.

Comment: [ESP8266 Soft Access Point Class](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/soft-access-point-examples.html) A soft access point is used when there is no internet or local WAN/LAN available.

Comment: The first block of code runs on the ESP8266 and connects to the wifi which is my CenuryLink router. The 2nd block of code bypasses the router and uses WiFi.softAP() to to define an access point to use as the server for the client which is the app running on the Android phone.

Comment: I can get it to barely work using WiFi.SoftAP but apparently, I'm not formatting the html right or something and it causes the connection to drop.